# How can I turn off journalling on an OS X boot disk?

Tags: ubuntu, formatting, osx-leopard, disk-utility

I'm new in all this OS X stuff. I'm running OS X 10.5 Leopard.

I want to be able to access and modify my disk under Ubuntu. For that I was told that I needed to turn of journalling on that disk. I've opened the disk utility, but the only way I've found to change the formating was to erase it. I have a huge amount of data which I can't erase.

I've searched Google, but haven't found exactly what I wanted.

Is there any other way to change this option without having to erase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/someVolume
```

Comment: Sorry but the error persist. "An error occured journaling the filesystem: The underlying task reported failure on exit (-9972)"
. I'm trying "diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/Time\ Machine/" with and without sudo.

Comment: Google says repair the drive with Disk Utility.

Answer (score 2):

`diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/Macintosh HD`
[[Via](http://hungrycoder.xenexbd.com/tutorial/readwrite-on-mac-osx-partition-from-ubuntu.html)]